# Android play ringtone from user input uri

Tags: android

My application has a button which allows the user to pick a ringtone from the phone. The code for that looks like this:

```
public void Btn_Ringtone_Click(View v){
    Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
    intent_upload.setType("audio/*");
    intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent_upload,1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){

    if((requestCode == 1) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)){
        ringtoneUri = data.getData();
        ringtoneLabel.setText(ringtoneUri.toString());
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

This seems to be working.

Later I want to use that same Uri together with a Media Player to play the chosen ringtone. My code for that looks like this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Log.i("My tag...", "Service started");

    String uriAsString = intent.getStringExtra("ASM_URI");
    Log.i("My tag...", uriAsString);

    //Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriAsString);
    //Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriAsString.replace("file:/", "file:///"));
    Uri uri = getContentUriForPath(uriAsString);

    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.create(this, uri);

    //mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
    //mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);

    /*
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), uri);
    ringtone.play();


    mp.start();

    this.stopSelf();
    */

    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

I have left commented code in, because those are the things I've tried - nothing has worked so far.

I believe the problem has to do with permissions, or the location of the file, or the URI itself. But I can't solve it.

As for permissions I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to the Manifest file.

According to my log the uri looks like this:

> content://media/external/audio/media/3250

which doesn't seem right... It didn't look like that at all in the ringtoneLabel after the file was picked.

**Question:** How do I properly pick, store, and play a URI from a local file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnPick, btnPlay, btnPause, btnStop;
private TextView txtSource;

final static int requestPick = 3;
private Uri fileUri;
final static int RQS_PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 4;
private MediaPlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnPick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPick);
    btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

    txtSource = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.srcFile);

    //Pick audio file
    btnPick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "ACTION_PICK"),
                    requestPick);
        }
    });

    //Play the selected audio
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (fileUri == null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "No file selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                playerPrepare();
                playerStart();
            }
        }
    });

    //Pause the player
    btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playerPause();
        }
    });

    //Stop the player
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playerStop();
        }
    });
}

private void playerStop() {
    player.stop();
}

private void playerPause() {
    player.pause();
}

private void playerStart() {
    player.start();
}

private void playerPrepare() {
    try {
        player.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == requestPick) {
            fileUri = data.getData();

            txtSource.setText(fileUri.toString());

            //Check and request Permission at runtime
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        RQS_PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                return;
            }

            resetPlayer();
            setPlayerSource(fileUri);
        }
    }
}

private void setPlayerSource(Uri fileUri) {
    try {
        player.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, fileUri);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void resetPlayer() {
    if (player == null) {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
    }
    player.reset();
}
```

}

The xml for this is....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="mjuyelrana.com.audioselect.MainActivity">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPick"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pick"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/srcFile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/source" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/play"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPause"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pause"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stop"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

And don't forget to add permission...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```